# how to restore the style of the datebox or datepicker in the GWT?

Tags: gwt

the style of the datebox or datepicker in my project is really mess up. the background and design of the date picker is missing i think. maybe my css is affecting them, I really don't know. is there a way to restore their original css or style?;

Answer (score 1):

Check your module's *.gwt.xml whether it has:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard"/>
```

And remove unnecessary class names and or style attributes which you have added.